# Oracle Apex Interactive Report vs Interactive Grid

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I've used them both, but I can't seem to find any advantage to Report vs Grid.
Grid gives the developer much more options and flexibility, and I didn't find any place that really compares pros and cons for each.
Any Reason to use Report over Grid?
Thanks

Comment: The main difference is that Interactive Reports came earlier, and Interactive Grid came later. There are still a few features that IRs have that IGs don't - but the stated direction from the APEX team is that eventually IGs will have all the features of the IR (plus more, obviously) and IRs might eventually be deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I developed a set of applications in APEX from 5.1 to 19c and I'd like both, IG and Reports, however I use them in different scenarios:

- Obviously if you want a IG for manipulation of data, then IG is your only option.
- If you want a Report, but you want to give the user endless options with it like download the content in csv, apply filters, create rules with the data visualisation like applying colours to rows that match different criteria. Then IG is your option
- If the report is static and you don't want any interaction on it, then use Report, it is much better for this scenario.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I use

- reports for *reporting* purposes - let users view data
- interactive grids to view data in a grid, along with possibility to edit existing values or add new rows *right here*

Although you can make both do what the "other" does (with more or less effort), their "natural" roles are as I previously said. To me, at least.

Comment: As you said, they both can do it with the same effort. The user don't really see any difference between report and grid. And for me, for example in Grid column there are many types I can choose (CheckBox, ColorPicker, Password... and much more) while Report have much less. I'm trying to understand if there is any reason to use report other than symantics

Comment: I'd say that you should use the one that suits your needs and fits end users' expectations.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found one big advantage to working with Interactive Report, when working with Files/Images.
Grid does not contain "Download BLOB" nor "Display Image" options in types, which makes it really hard to work with, and creating many compatibility problems.

I've wasted 2 days trying to work with files in Grid but still failed, while in Report I managed to do that in a couple of hours and it works.

For all other types, I guess Grid is better.